# Error:SQL Server Import data to a new database

Tags: sql-server, mysqlimport

Trying to import data into a new database with SQL Server Management Studio's Import and Export Wizard.Shows an error below:

> Warning 0x80049304:Data Flow Task 1: Warrning: Could not open global
>   flow performance counters are not available.To resolve, run this
>   package as an administrator, or on the wywtem's console

Please tell me what should I do? Thanks

(SQL Server 2012 64 bit, Windows 7)

Comment: Have you read the warning message and followed the instructions? :)

Answer (score 1):

**To resolve, run this
package as an administrator
, or on the wywtem's console**

personally I think you should try this first. Then if that fails - tell us what it says.